# Alternatives to react-native-date-picker?

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am trying to use the `react-native-date-picker` on my vanilla react native project (no expo). I followed all of the installation instructions, but any time I attempt to render the `DatePicker` I get the following error...

```
[Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNDatePicker" was not found in the UIManager.]
```

Now, when I check the documentation, I can see that it looks like I need to declare `<RNDateTimePicker mode="date" />` somewhere, but the documentation is so piss poor, I have no idea where to put it in the file or in relation to the date picker object. The documentation through and through is petulantly unhelpful, to say it positively. Does anyone know how to fix this issue, where to put that magic line, or have any idea what DatePickers aren't inherently broken with the documentation skills of a 2nd grader?

Comment: are you creating a new android build and checking after installing the package?

Comment: Using iOS currently, but yes I followed the installation instructions on their GitHub README